# Show that if $3n + 5$ is even, then $n^2$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, parity

What approach should I take to prove this?

Comment: Hint: $n^2$ is odd if and only if $n$ is.

Answer (score 3):

If $3n+5$ is even, then $3n$ is odd (since odd+odd=even, even+odd=odd, even+even=even). Then, $n$ must be odd, since odd*odd = odd, even*odd=even, even*even=even. Since odd*odd=odd, $n^2$ is also odd.

Comment: I know that n = 2k (even),
n = 2k+1 (odd)
Can you explain in terms of these and show some working? Explanations in paragraphs like these wont be accepted.

Comment: Feel free to do your own homework by filling in the details on your own.

Comment: I would certainly accept this.

Comment: If it was to Show that if  3n+5 is even, then  n is odd...I would have gone for the direct proof taking n = 2k+1
But here its n^2...i needed a straight value of n to input in (3n+5)...thats what confusing me how to do so.

Comment: You should be able to show odd+odd=even, even+odd=odd, etc. Try those first.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick proof if you know modular arithmetic.

$3n \equiv -5 \equiv - 3 \pmod 2$

$n \equiv -1 \pmod 2$ (division permitted because $(3,2) = 1$)

$n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ (QED)